# ¿Como se llama el color de la pulpa de aguacate?

Tags: vocabulario, colores

En inglés, "avocado" es el nombre de la fruta aguacate, y también el color de la pulpa de la fruta.

¿Es lo mismo en español?  o si no, ¿cuál nombre se usa para el color de la pulpa de la aguacate?

Comment: No es el color de la pulpa. La pulpa es green, yellowish-green y greenish-yellow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Más allá del nombre específico, en general los nombres de los colores son bastante escasos. Teniendo en cuenta que una persona en condiciones normales es capaz de visualizar más de doscientas tonalidades diferentes, no existe tal cantidad de nombres para definir colores. Por lo general las reglas son las siguientes:

- Nombre del color: azul, amarillo, verde, etc
- Respecto a la variable de color de tono: azul verdoso, verde amarillento, etc.
- A un objeto: esmeralda, rubí, cielo, arena.
- Respecto a una de las variables que no definen el tono que son brillo y saturación: azul claro, rojo oscuro, rosa saturado.
- Combinación tono-objeto: verde militar, azul marino, rosa chicle.

Los idiomas latinos se ven favorecidos por algo externo al color en sí, la estética y solo por los colores de los tintes de cabello: caoba, azabache, platino, rubio, ceniza, pelirrojo.

La moda tiene su aporte asignando nombres a colores que en mayor o menor medida se adaptan al uso cotidiano: color camel, colores makeup, rojo Valentino, verde Benetton, donde más allá de la aceptación popular, definen una tonalidad.

Respecto a la pregunta, no creo exista un nombre específico para la pulpa del aguacate, ya que de por sí no posee un solo color, sino más bien varios en degradado. Podríamos hacer una descomposición siguiendo las reglas anteriores e intentando seguir terminología en uso.

El ejercicio es: ¿Cómo describirías estos siete colores por teléfono?

[image]

1. Verde oliva
2. Verde manzana
3. Verde amarillento
4. Amarillo verdoso
5. Verde pálido
6. Amarillo pálido
7. Mantequilla

Al menos que yo sepa no existe una palabra para el color de la pulpa del aguacate, como tantas otras palabras que existen en inglés y no tienen correlatividad en Español (y viceversa).

De todas ellas me quedaría con: – *La pulpa del aguacate es color mantequilla verdoso o simplemente color mantequilla.*–

**Actualización después de los comentarios**

El color del guacamole suele ser más homogéneo que el color de la pulpa del fruto ya que es una combinación de todas las tonalidades descritas. El nombre que en español se asigna al verde amarillento claro del guacamole es **verde pistacho**.

[image]

<sub>*[Enlace de la imagen](https://casaycolor.com/verde-pistacho/)*</sub>

Comment: En inglés creo que el color "avocado" es más cerca a verde oliva.  Pero gracias para los demás colores

Comment: Quizás confundas *pulpa de aguacate* con *guacamole*, los colores son diferentes.

Comment: Guacamole recibe su color principalmente del color de la aguacate.  Si es más verde, entonces la pulpa de la aguacate es más verde.

Comment: mmmhhhh... no sé si es del todo correcto. El guacamole es pulpa de aguacate que, además de combinada con otros ingredientes, la oxidación hace que cambie de color. Tal como lo que pasa con una manzana, el interior es de un color y pasado un rato de otro.

Comment: No sé que te pones en tu guacamole, pero en mio solo la aguacate es verde en el fresco.  rsrsrs

Comment: Respuesta actualizada.

Comment: avocado as a color sounds like marketing.

Comment: Yes It does, or maybe a localism. I wrote a question about It on [Meta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4467/acerca-de-localismos-en-el-c%c3%b3digo-de-conducta)

Answer (score 0):

No soy muy bueno para detectar tonalidades ni para saberme sus nombres, pero creo que el aguacate es **[verde lima](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lima_(color))**. (Por cierto, en Chile al fruto lo llamamos *palta* y al color *verde limón*).

Answer (score 0):

En la información general que se da sobre el aguacate se dice;

"*La pulpa es aceitosa **de color crema a verde amarillento**, con un sabor similar a la nuez. Posee una única semilla redondeada de color pardo claro y 2-4 cm, que aparece recubierta de una delgada capa leñosa. El fruto es una baya "unisemillada", oval , de superficie lisa o rugosa*".

Por tanto, para el color de la pulpa del aguacate, igualmente es correcto decir que es de "**color crema**" o "*de crema a verde amarillento*".

Crema (color)

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crema_(color)

> La crema es el color de la nata que produce el ganado que pasta en
> pastos naturales con plantas ricas en pigmentos carotenoides amarillos
> , algunos de los cuales se incorporan a la leche fresca (en concreto,
> la grasa butírica). Esto le da un tono amarillo a la leche que de otro
> modo sería blanca en concentraciones de grasa más altas (por lo que el
> color de la crema de leche podría considerarse a medio camino entre
> los colores de la leche de vaca natural y la mantequilla). El crema es
> el color pastel del amarillo, al igual que el rosa lo es del rojo . Al
> mezclar amarillo y blanco, se puede producir crema.

Comment: Aquí;                                                   
https://www.frutas-hortalizas.com/Frutas/Presentacion-Aguacate.html#:~:text=de%20la%20variedad.-,La%20pulpa%20es%20aceitosa%20de%20color%20crema%20a%20verde%20amarillento,de%20superficie%20lisa%20o%20rugosa.

Comment: Quizás debas aclarar acerca de localismos. El concepto crema en España es muy diferente al de latino América, donde crema es la nata de leche, color blanco o blanco sucio.

Comment: color crema solito? No creo. verde amarillento.